# How do attention network works?

Tags: text, nlp, transformer-model, attention-model

Recently I was going through Attention is all you need paper, ongoing through it I found an issue regarding understanding the attention network if I ignore the maths behind it.
Can anyone make me understand the attention network with an example?

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer/) tutorial illustrates each core component in Transformer and definitely worth reading.

Intuitively, the attention mechanisms are trying to find the "similar" timestep according to an attention function (e.g. projection + cosine similarity in Attention is all you need), then compute the new representation with the accordingly calculated weight and previous representations.